# how to keep request url in flask redirect call

Tags: apache, redirect, flask

I'm using flask with apache frontend. When making a call to some endpoint, e.g. /app, I want to keep original url while in Flask redirect call to another backend. If I use this Flask logic

```
@app.route('/app')
def app():
    # some logic here
    return redirect(uri, code=302) # let's say uri=http://backend:port
```

and I invoke a call with `http://host:port/app` this will call above snippet and invoke the redict to uri. What I get back in my browser is `http://backend:port` instead of `http://host:port/app`. The question is how to redirect the call in Flask and keep original request url in apache rather then get redirect uri.

Comment: Did you maybe solve it meanwhile? Because I'm struggling to do the same.

Comment: I didn't find a way to do it in flask, but it can solved using apache frontend with mod_rewrite rule, something like: RewriteRule /app http://backend:port [QSA,P,L,NE]